# How to use multi-cursor with regex search in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use multi-cursor to select multiple occurrences of a regular expression search in Visual Studio Code, but I can't figure out how to make multi-cursor use the regex pattern instead of just the selected text.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Search for my regular expression using the "Find" featureCmd + F).
2. Put my cursor in the text editor at the location where I want to start my multi-cursor selection.
3. Press Cmd + D to select the next occurrence of the selected text.
4. Repeat step 3 until I've selected all the occurrences I want.

Problem is, when you the text editor (step 2), it's not using the regex pattern anymore.

How can I use multi-cursor with regex search in Visual Studio Code?

- Is there a setting I need to change?
- Is there a different workflow I should follow?
- Is there an extension that solves the problem?

Comment: why not just use regex-mode search and replace?

Comment: because I'm not trying to do a simple replace, I am trying to find complex patterns then type new code at the anywhere in the line.

Comment: I can remember I used `Ctrl+D` and it worked with a regex search, but it does not work anymore in a recent version (>= 1.62), Now `Ctrl+D` copies the current selection to the find box and gone is the regex.

Comment: @rioV8 thanks for saying that, I remember it used to work as well, did not occur to me that it is a broken feature, I thought I was just using it wrong.

Answer (score 5):

1. in the find dialog enter your required regex search
2. still in the find dialog execute command: `editor.action.selectAllMatches` (`Alt+Enter`)
3. now all occurrences in editor are selected with multi cursor
4. `Alt+click` a selection if you want to remove it from the set

If needed select a region of the file first. When opening the find dialog click the **Find in Selection** button (3 lines) first.

1. in the find dialog enter your required regex search
2. one of the following:

   - with the cursor in the Find dialog, execute `editor.action.selectAllMatches` (`Alt+Enter`)
   - click in the editor and execute command: **Selection** > **Select All Occurrences** `editor.action.selectHighlights` (`Ctrl+Shift+L`)
3. now all occurrences in editor are selected with multi cursor
4. `Alt+click` a selection if you want to remove it from the set

After you have done your edits and you still have multi cursors:

- press as many times `Esc` till they are gone
- click anywhere with the mouse in the editor not near a cursor

Some Emmet commands remove the multi cursor. So sometimes you have to do the selection again or change the order of your edits.